# How to download files to SFTP folder in Brave?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, download, sftp

I am using Brave on Arch linux with Gnome and when I want to download files on a SFTP folder (mounted via gnome GUI).

I manage to start the download process and I get the saving location dialog as usual, but once I select the SFTP folder then press "save", the popup vanishes but the file isn't saved. If I were to select a local folder, the download would then start and would be visible in the downloads tab.

I tried with Firefox and everything goes well, i.e. the file is saved on the remote location.

Is it possible to do and if so, which setting should I change ?

Comment: At what point in the process does "nothing happen and the popup vanishes"? Please list the steps of this process and what happens at each point so that we can better understand what your issue may actually be. Use the EDIT button to improve your question.

Comment: @music2myear Alright, I edited it andI hope it helps

Comment: check the owner &permission of sftp folder

Comment: @petepf It works on FF so I'd assume it's not related to it. Can you elaborate on what you think I should do ? Which permission settings should I exactly have ?